# Update Selected Row Entity Framework MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, radio-button

I want to be able to select a row in a table (which represents an invoice), choose a radio button which has an amount value and press 'Confirm'. Once confirm is clicked, I want the status of the selected invoice to change to "Paid" or "Partly Paid" depending on the payment amount select. I also want a new payment entry to be added to the ClientPayments table that is related to the selected invoice, I want the PaymentAmount to be the radio button amount and the date to be the system date.

The code I have at the moment is producing an error, namely: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'.

Here is the code I have so far. In the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "InvoiceController"))
{

foreach (var item in Model)
{
string selectedRow = "";
if (item.InvoiceNumberID == ViewBag.InvoiceNumberID)
{
    selectedRow = "selectedRow";
} 

<tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top">
            <td> 
           <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='select' data-id=@item.InvoiceNumberID     >Select</a>


        </td> 
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceNumberID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceStatus)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client.FullName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.InvoiceNumberID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.InvoiceNumberID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.InvoiceNumberID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value='0' />
}
</table>
<br />

<p><i>Select or type in a custom amount to confirm as paid:</i>
</p>
<table>
<tr><td><b>Monthly Amounts:</b></td><td><b>Weekly Amounts:</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Private Lesson (1 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "640", true) R640.00<br  /></td><td>Private Lesson (1 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "160", true) R160.00<br /> </td></tr>
<tr><td>Private Lesson (1/2 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "350", true) R350.00<br  /></td><td>Private Lesson (1 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "87.50", true) R87.50<br  /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Group Lesson (1 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "460", true) R460.00</td>  <td>Private Lesson (1 Hour) @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "115", true) R115.00<br /></td> </tr>
<tr><td>Custom Amount @Html.RadioButton("InvoiceAmount", "115", true)  @Html.TextBox("customAmount")<br /></td></tr>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('.select').click(function(){
            $('#id').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
                 alert($('#id').val());
             });
</script>
```

Confirm Payment

And the code in the controller is:

```
    public ActionResult Confirm(int id, long InvoiceAmount)
    {
        Invoices invoices = db.Invoice.Find(id);
        //now validate that if the logged in user is authorized to select and confirm this invoice or not.


        if (InvoiceAmount != invoices.InvoiceAmount)
        {
            invoices.InvoiceStatus = "Partly Paid";

        }
        else
        {
            invoices.InvoiceStatus = "Confirmed";
        }
        db.Entry(invoices).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

The javascript alert shows the right ID that I select, but when I click Confirm, it doesn't find the ID. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Amy

Comment: What does the element look like that contains the id attribute you select with $('#id') ?

Comment: The element should be any row that is selected by pressing the 'Select' link. Like <td><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='select' data-id=@item.InvoiceNumberID >Select</a></td>

Comment: So the 'id' must return the InvoiceNumberID of the selected row

Comment: I apoligize for my question, it seems that the opera browser I am using on my android phone does an invalid render of the Html provided. 80% of the view code is not shown.

Comment: In the code for the view you give, where is your submit button? or how do you otherwise submit your form? I just tested it (with putting a submit button inside the form) and the code just works fine.

Comment: At the bottom of the page (for some reason, it didn't come out here in the code block), I have: <a href='@Url.Action("Confirm", "Invoice")'>
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/buttons/confirmpmtbtn.png")' alt='Confirm Payment' />
</a>. So it's an action link, not a button and it's not within the form. Could that be why it's not working?

Comment: If it is outside of your form, then it's probably the cause, yes.

Comment: But can I still use an Action within the form or must it be a button with the input type = submit?

Comment: It's either; a)  a submit button, b) an action link (Url.Action) which you'll have to modify with javascript so the id parameter is applied (not the nicest way to do it) or c) use jquery [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Aha, I see now :) So I also had to move all the radio buttons into the form. Thanks! It works now. Could you quickly tell me, what would I add to the controller to add a new entry for a payment?(one that relates to the selected invoice) The status of the invoice changed to 'Confirmed'. But I also want to add a new entry into the ClientPayments table, and I've never done it like this with MVC before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For the postback to work, you need to submit your form properly, for instance have a submit button inside your form;
2) For adding a new entry to the ClientPayments table, you do something along the line of

```
if (InvoiceAmount != invoices.InvoiceAmount)
{
    invoices.InvoiceStatus = "Partly Paid";
}
else
{
    invoices.InvoiceStatus = "Confirmed";
}
db.Entry(invoices).State = EntityState.Modified;

var clientPayment = new ClientPayment();
// Set clientPayment properties
db.ClientPayments.Add(clientPayment);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question - how would I set PaymentDate to the current system date? Is there some easy way of saying clientPayment.PaymentDate = *sort sore of now date*?

Comment: [Here](http://www.google.se/search?q=C%23+current+date) you can find more information

Comment: I mean clientPayments.PaymentDate = systemdate? I didn't realise that asterixs made weird formatting

Comment: [DateTime.UtcNow or DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)